# Using wild character at setTypeAliasesPackage (MyBatis) with java config

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-java-config, type-alias

I want to set typeAliases with MyBatis and Spring boot, but I can't use "*" in package name.

For example,

```
SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(applicationContext.getResources("classpath:/mapper/**/*.xml"));
sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("board.board.entity");
sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfiguration(mybatisConfig());

return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
```

In this code, the package for typeAliasesPackage is "board.board.entity".

What I want to set the package is like "board.**(any packages).entity".

I have a lot of entity package and don't want to set typeAliases each package.

Is there any way to set typeAliasesPackage just once?

Comment: How did you solve it? I've the same problem, do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.zhu8fei.**.mybatis.model");
```

Can you try this and let me know.

Comment: Not work, very slow, it took 3 hours to start a project. I used "com.zhu8fei.*.mybatis.model" in the past year, it was ok, but nowadays, it took so long time immediately

Comment: please use your package structure.. I just gave "com.zhu8fei.*.mybatis.model" as an example

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own package, I gave that as an example too. It's strange everyone is ok except me